# Correctly synchronizing Vector in java threads

Tags: java, multithreading, vector, synchronization

In a classic consumer\producer threads senario and i have to use a vector for the queue.
Since I need one thread to wait to the other until there's an element in the vector, i tried the following method:

```
public synchronized  QueueLine getCustomer(int index)
    {
        while (Customers.isEmpty())
        {
            try 
            {
                wait();
            } 
            catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }
        return Customers.elementAt(index);
    }
```

while the other thread adds to the "customers" vector and than use notify.
i know i'm doing something worng since once the notify() doesn't effects the other thread.

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't effects?" Do you mean the call to  getCustomer() doesn't return? Can you expand the code into a more complete test scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are synchronizing on the consumer instance. I think you should synchronize on the `Vector`:

```
public QueueLine getCustomer(int index) {
    synchronized (Customers) {        
        while (Customers.isEmpty()) {
            Customers.wait();
        } 
        return Customers.elementAt(index);
    }
}
```

In the producer, you should do the same: synchronize and notify on the `Vector`.

Comment: Since he calls notifyAll() even outside threads waiting on the object shouldn't matter for the threads itself, so I don't see how this would be a problem (well you'd wake up objects in a way that wasn't expected by the programmer, but it wouldn't be a problem for the shown code)

Comment: @Voo I do not understand what you mean. What I mean is that synchronization should happen on the common object (the vector). If the consumer waits on itself and the producer notifies on itself then the program will not work.

Comment: Well I'd assume they were waiting on the same instance, using this instead of a private locking object can be problematic. ie someone has a reference to the instance and calls wait() on it - if you use only notify you just woke up an independent thread and lost an update - which obviously can lead to problems but wouldn't have been a problem in this case (for the consumer/producer at least). Didn't even think of him waiting on different objects ;)

Comment: That is why complete examples are better: we can see the whole thing and its particularities.

Comment: hey guys. i'm affraid they both were waiting\notifying the same object (same refrence). as for the solution @gpeche wrote it does make sense to use the vector object and so i does work but better but not completly. but on the other hand, there's a new warning when i synchronizing using the vector: "synchronization on non-final field"
what does it means?

Comment: Consider thread 1 (consumer) calling obj.wait(), thread 2 (maverick) doing obj = <another object> and thread 3 doing obj.notifyAll(). Synchronization fails in this case as thread 1 and thread 3 are actually synchronizing on different objects. If your synchronization works on a final field, this cannot happen.

Comment: I made a mistake and didn't connect the the consumer and producer to the same queue. thank you all for your help

Answer (score 1):

Well this should actually work and is one of the usual methods to implement this (ie if something doesn't work there's probably a bug in the other half of your code we don't see here). But really there's no reason to implement something like this yourself (except for homework ;)) since there's the perfectly fine java concurrent package which has several possible solutions for this problem.

The 1:1 implementation of what you want would be a [BlockingQueue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) (well one of its implementations - pick one that best fits your model).

If you really need to use a class that has been deprecated since java 1.2 or so, you should post more of your code so we can figure out what exactly is wrong.

Comment: I know about BlockingQueue and you are right about the homework assignment.

Comment: the other half is simply:
public synchronized void insert(int arrival)
    {
        ID = EntranceLine.size()+1;
        QueueLine newCustomer = new QueueLine(ID, ServiceType, arrival);
        EntranceLine.add(newCustomer);
        notifyAll();
    }

Comment: Sorry to say, but the code should work just fine. notifyAll is actually not necessary since you can indefinitely add elements to your vector (it'd only make sense if the producer could also stall because he can't add an object - which can't happen in your code), but it shouldn't matter. The consumer vector is a field in your class and you aren't waiting on the object somewhere else in your code?

Comment: You are inserting into `EntranceLine` but in your consumer you read from `Customers`. Unless they reference the same vector, it is logical that your consumer remains waiting forever.

Comment: nice catch gpeche. You should update your answer so he can accept it.

Comment: @gpeche, you were right the first time, they are references to the same vector.